# How would I round the output of the code?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming (Just started yesterday) and I was trying to make a calculator that when given input for the variables, it would come up with the number. It worked fine, but I wanted to make it so that the output that the code had at the end would be rounded. How would I round the output of the code?

```
print("What is the Initial Principal Value?")

P = int(input())
print("What is the interest rate?")
r = float(input())

print("What is the number of times interest is applied per time period")
n = int(input())

print("Finally, what is the number of time periods elapsed, this must be typed in terms of annual circumstances.")
t = int(input())
      
print(P*(1+(r/n))**(n/t))

round()
```

Comment: `round(P*(1+(r/n))**(n/t),2)`?  You're missing the arguments in `round()`.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
print("What is the Initial Principal Value?")

P = int(input())
print("What is the interest rate?")
r = float(input())

print("What is the number of times interest is applied per time period")
n = int(input())

print("Finally, what is the number of time periods elapsed, this must be typed in terms of annual circumstances.")
t = int(input())

result = round(P * (1 + (r / n)) ** (n / t), 2)
print(result)
```